# ASP Creating Button Programmatically in specialize location from configuration in a Datatable utilizing MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

What I have going on is a Master Page, that has the following ContactPlaceHolder

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContactPlaceHolder_Header" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Inside of this placeholder, I want to dynamically create buttons based on results of a sqlquer that are pushed into a DataTable.

So basically i'm kind of looking for

```
foreach(DataRow dtRow in ButtonsDT.Rows)
    { 
Button btnNew = new Button();    
btnNew .ID = dtRow["ID"].Tostring()};    
btnNew .Text = "Save";  

    }
```

I realize that is how you create the button, but how do I place it in that specific ContentPlaceHolder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get reference to the master page contentplaceholder then you can add dynamic controls in it.

Code Behind:

```
Control masterc = Master.FindControl("ContactPlaceHolder_Header");
foreach(DataRow dtRow in ButtonsDT.Rows)
{ 
    Button btnNew = new Button();    
    btnNew.ID = dtRow["ID"].Tostring()};    
    btnNew.Text = "Save";  

     // add button in panel or placeholder
    masterc.Controls.Add(btnNew);
}
```

Comment: Waqar i cant fidn the namespace for Master.FindContorl

Comment: master is the property of Page class.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

ContactPlaceHolder_Header.Controls.Add(btnNew);

Comment: really?  If it thats simple i'm going to kick myseld

Comment: @Ras how you have access contentpalceholder in codebehind directly ? i'm surprised.